# Get coordinates of text selection and apply tailwindcss styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a paragraph of text. My goal is when the user selects a text (either from left to right, or right to left), I want to display a dropdown menu positioned at the end of the selection (they call it focusNode in the Selection API).

I'm using TailwindCSS to apply the classNames top and left dynamically.

Here's how I'm calculating the x and y coordinates:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleSelection = () => {
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
      const text = window.getSelection().toString();
      if (!text) return;
      setSelectedText(text);
      setMenuX(`left-[${rect.left}px]`);
      setMenuY(`top-[${rect.top}px]`);
      setIsOpen(true);
    };

    const handleDeselect = () => {
      setSelectedText('');
      setIsOpen(false);
    };

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleSelection);
    document.addEventListener('selectionchange', handleDeselect);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleSelection);
      document.removeEventListener('selectionchange', handleDeselect);
    };
  }, [selectedText]);
```

When logging the menuX and menuY, they seem to be changing correctly. However the position of the dropdown component isn't changing.

Here's the dropdown component:

```
const DropdownMenu = ({ menuX, menuY }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`absolute ${menuX} ${menuY} w-40 p-2 bg-white shadow-md rounded-md`}
    >
      <ul>
        <li className="p-2 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer rounded-md transition duration-200">
          <a href="#">Action 1</a>
        </li>
        <li className="p-2 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer rounded-md transition duration-200">
          <a href="#">Action 2</a>
        </li>
        <li className="p-2 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer rounded-md transition duration-200">
          <a href="#">Action 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm passing `menuX` and `menuY` as props and injecting them in the className string.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Tailwindcss doesn't generate every css class possible. It scans your files, and generates a css file accordingly. Instead of using class name, just use inline styles. menuX and menuY should be numbers. [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

```
    <div
      className={`absolute w-40 p-2 bg-white shadow-md rounded-md`}
      style={{left: menuX, top: menuY}}
    >
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. Appreciate that. However, only when selecting from left to right, it seems like the dropdown is positioned at the start of the selection not the end. Any quick fixes or should I make a new post?

Comment: If you want it at the end of the selection, you probably want to use rect.right and rect.bottom instead of rect.left and rect.top